# MEAN delete. Only working once

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have a very simple MEAN stack app. I'm almost done with it however I have one little bug.

When I go to delete a line it deletes it fine. However when I try to remove a second or third one etc. It will only remove it from the scope. I have to refresh first for the delete to work on the server side again.

Angular code below

```
  $scope.deleteNote = function(city){


     $http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/city',
    data: city.city,
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"} });


    var index = $scope.cities.indexOf(city.city);
    var cityindex = city.city;



    console.log(cityindex + " at " + index);
    console.log(cityindex);
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.cities.splice(index, 1);

};
```

Node side code

```
app.delete('/city', function(req,res){

CityDb.findOneAndRemove({city: req.body.city}, function(err, results){
    if (err) throw err;

});

});
```

So whats going on?

site on heroku
https://serene-springs-2108.herokuapp.com/#/

github for full code

https://github.com/jminterwebs/STBExpress/tree/MEAN/Public/javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error you're getting in your app (perhaps because so many people are now deleting stuff from your live site!), but your server is not responding to your delete request, which causes errors in the console and also means your angular frontend can get out of sync.

Firstly, respond to the request in your express app like this:

```
app.delete('/city', function(req,res){

  CityDb.findOneAndRemove({city: req.body.city}, function(err, results){

    if (err){
      res.status(500).send({error: err});
      // Assume you are going to catch this somewhere...
      throw err;
    }

    else
      res.status(200).send();

  });

});
```

And secondly, only have the item removed from your angular scope when the deletion has been confirmed successful:

```
$scope.deleteNote = function(city){

  // Make the request
  $http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/city',
    data: city.city,
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"} 
  })
  // On success:
  .then(function (){
    var index = $scope.cities.indexOf(city.city);
    var cityindex = city.city;
    $scope.cities.splice(index, 1);
  })
  // On error:
  .catch(function (){
    // Do something better than this:
    alert("Something bad happened");
  })

  .finally(function (){
    // Re-enable the button.
    city.deleting = false;
  })

  // Disable the delete button and show a loading animation based on
  // this value (use `ng-disabled`).
  city.deleting = true;


};
```

The above will ensure your view is accurate and aligned with what's going on on the server.